# How do I implement Facebook's new Registration Tool using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So Facebook have just updated their login/connect product with this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration

I was wondering if anyone had taken the opportunity to play around with it and, if so, whether they'd be happy to help a nuby implement this as the only signup form for a site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://veerasundaravel.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/facebook-registration-plugin-in-rails/

Answer (score 0):

> [Facebooker2] Provides rails helpers for interfacing with Facebook's OpenGraph Javascript
>   API, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/.

Check out this library:
https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2

Comment: Thanks for this. I checked it out but doesn't seem to have great support for the new type of login.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. https://github.com/grosser/rpx_now
2. https://github.com/slainer68/devise_rpx_connectable
3. https://github.com/grimen/devise_facebook_connectable.git